# Utilization Factor, periodic tasks and schedulability

Tags: operating-systems, scheduling, real-time

We have 2 periodic tasks that start at the same moment in a monocore processor.
Why can happen that, even if the utilization factor is <= 1, the 2 periodic tasks are not schedulable ?

For example, in this picture the 2 tasks are schedulable, but if i increase the computation time of the first task of 1 ms, we've got that the utilization factor is 1, but the 2 task are no longer schedulable.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've already answered your own question.  You ask "why is this possible?" and then shown an example where it happens.  I'm not sure what more there is to say -- it is possible that they're not schedulable because there exists example where they aren't schedulable, and you've shown one.  What more do you want?  What more can you expect?  What are you looking for an answer to explain?  What exactly is your question?  Perhaps you should turn it around and ask  yourself, why would you think it is *not* possible?

Comment: To me seems intuitive that if utilization factor is 1, then the task ARE schedulable. So, probably i have not clearly understood what utilization factor stands for. And why an utiization factor of 1 doesnt imply the schedulability

Comment: Perhaps you might want to explore where that intuition comes from and why you think utilization factor = 1 should imply schedulability, and then edit the question to show your thoughts.  Note that utilization factor $< 1$ and $> 1$ are probably simpler to think about than utilization factor exactly equal to 1 -- the latter is right on a boundary, and anything can happen there.